# AngularJS version in KendoUI and Wijmo5

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, wijmo

I am looking at using KendoUI or Wijmo 5 for my next AngularJS project. What is the current version of AngularJS in KendoUI and Wijmo5?

Answer (score 2):

Now wijmo 5 can also be used with angular2. Here is the [link](https://wijmo.com/blog/introducing-the-angular-2-explorer-for-wijmo-5/).

Answer (score 1):

At the moment,

KendoUI is using AngularJS 1.3.0 which we can tell from [KendoUI Core Github repository](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-ui-core/blob/master/src/angular.js).

Wijmo 5 is using AngularJS 1.2.19 which we can tell from the [Wijmo 5 Explorer AngularJS demo](http://demos.componentone.com/wijmo/5/Angular/Explorer/Explorer/#/).

Answer (score 0):

The information above is a bit out of date.

Wijmo is currently using AngularJS v1.3.15 as of this date.